# Visual Studio Code: Multiple spaces-per-tab setting in a single file - possible?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, yaml, liquid, locomotivecms

I am working with Liquid files (.liquid extension) that have a YAML section at the start.

e.g.

```
settings:
- label: "bla bla bla"
  id: some_id
  type: select
  options:
  - label: "Option 1"
  value: option-1
  - label: "Option 2"
  value: option-2
---
{% for item in array.items %}
    <div id="{{ liquid_array | filter }}">
        {% if liquid_object = some_condition %}
            // do some stuff
        {% else %}
            // do some other stuff
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The preferred tab spacing for YAML is [2 spaces](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/master/topics/troubleshooting/yaml_idiosyncrasies.html#:%7E:text=Indentation,uniform%20and%20not%20deeply%20nested.). (And certainly for the environment I'm working in (Locomotive CMS) a 4-space tab setting causes issues when the file is pushed to the server).

I prefer to work with 4-space tabs for HTML and liquid though.

**Is there any way to get VS Code to allow 2-space tabs in one part of a file and 4-space tabs in another part of the same file?**

It appears [VS Code detects file type based on the file extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) and I understand that you can set tab spacing based on file type, but this obviously won't solve my problem. I was wondering if there is any way to get VS Code to detect the file type based on the markup structure? Perhaps the I could set a tab-space setting for YAML and a tab-space setting for HTML and both would be applied with a .liquid file...?